# How to access button of div that has no name attribute in selenium web driver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have written this code and want to log in to **Twitter** with a `selenium` `web driver`. But after
filling in **username** I am unable to **click** the **next** button as it does not have `name` or `id` attributes. How can I do it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en-gb")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_name('text').send_keys('username')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('').click()

time.sleep(3)
print('TEst Completed')
```

Comment: you could try to use xpath or css selector to find that button, I haven't login into the page but something like: 
`dirver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Next'")`
something like this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome you can bring up the inspector by right-mouse clicking on the element of interest (the `Next` button) and selecting Inspect from the popup). Then in the Inspector window, right-mouse click on the element you are interested in (it should already be highlighted), and select `Copy` and then `Copy full XPath`. You can then paste the result in to a `find_element_by_xpath` call.

As an aside, using `time.sleep` calls are fine if you want your program to run in slow motion so you can see what is happening, but if you want it to run at top speed, you should initially call `driver.implcitly_wait(n)` where `n` is some number of seconds (for example, 3). Then when you do a find_element call following `driver.get`, the driver will wait for up to 3 seconds for the desired element to appear before timing out but will not wait any longer than necessary.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    # Wait for up to 3 seconds (but maybe less) for sought after
    # elemt to appear:
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en-gb")
    driver.find_element_by_name('text').send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/span/span').click()
    print('Test Completed')
except Exception as e:
    print("Got exception:", e)
finally:
    # Come here even on exceptions to be sure we "quit" the driver:
    input('Pausing until you hit enter...')
    driver.quit()
```

**Update**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sir please can you explain how you wrote this path `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/span/span').click()`

Comment: Read the answer again. There I attempted to explain in complete detail how I came up with this path. I 've updated the answer adding a few screen captures,

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element <kbd>Next</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *`text()`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Next')]").click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

No every element will have some fixed `id` or `name` or even `class` attribute.
In this particular case elements are having dynamic class names, so the most stable approach here will to use the `Next` text.
This can be done with XPath locator, as following:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Next']").click()
```